# NetworkManager CLI hotspot: 802.1X supplicant took too long to authenticate

Tags: wpa-supplicant, nmcli, ap-hotspot

I am trying to create a wifi hotspot/AP using NetworkManager CLI (`nmcli`).

All works well if I create it for `2.4GHz band=bg`. But, if I set `band=a` for 5GHz, I get a timeout failure from `wpa_supplicant`

This occurs on 2 different systems.  One is ubuntu 20.04 with Qualcomm wifi device.  The other ubuntu 18.04 with Intel wifi device.  Both devices are capable of 5GHz.
I need help determining what's wrong.. please.

This command for `band=bg` is successful:

```
> nmcli device wifi hotspot ifname [wifi_dev] band bg ssid [MyWiFi] password [MyPassword]
Device '[wifi_device]' successfully activated with '[4-part hex number id]'
```

Then delete it:

```
> nmcli con delete Hotspot  (that's the default hotspot connection name)
```

Then changing to `band=a` fails:

```
> nmcli device wifi hotspot ifname [wifi_dev] band a ssid [MyWiFi] password [MyPassword]
Error: Connection activation failed: 802.1X supplicant took too long to authenticate
```